# Woocommerce add Account and Basket in menu

Tags: php, woocommerce

Having recently worked on a project requiring an icon for the connections page and also the cart,
I haven't found much on this problem.

Comment: Okay, this is better, but I am still a little hesitant to call it a proper question if there is no question with a question mark at the end.  Something along the lines of *How do I...?* or *How can I add... in Woocommerce?*

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to activate it.

First, go to woocommerce.php and look for this line.

```html
/**
 * Sample implementation of the WooCommerce Mini Cart.
 *
 * You can add the WooCommerce Mini Cart to header.php like so ...
 *
 *<?php
 *  if ( function_exists( 'godault_metal_woocommerce_header_cart' ) ) {
 *          godault_metal_woocommerce_header_cart();
 *      }
 *?>
 */
```

Then you must uncomment it and your cart will be activated.

To display it, just add your corresponding function in your header.php

```html
<div class="panier">
 <?php 
      if ( function_exists( 'godault_metal_woocommerce_header_cart' ) ) {
          godault_metal_woocommerce_header_cart();
          }
 ?>
</div><!--#cart -->
```

Then finally to activate put a link to the user account do the same.

Go to woocommerce.php add this by changing the name of the function.

```html
if (! function_exists('godault_metal_woocommerce_header_account')) {
    /**
     * Display Header Account.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    function godault_metal_woocommerce_header_account() {
        ?>
        <div class="header-my-account">
            <div class="header-login"> 
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink(get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id'))); ?>" title="Account">
                    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Add it in the header.php.

```html
<div class="account">
                <?php
                    if (    function_exists('godault_metal_woocommerce_header_account')) {
                        godault_metal_woocommerce_header_account();
                    }
                ?>
</div><!--#account -->
```